# CPack building external autogen project with bad output location

Tags: linux, cmake, cpack

I'm trying to build a debian using CMake `ExternalProject_Add` on a autogen based project.  The project installs to whatever prefix directory I set (defaults to `/usr/local`).  The problem is, when I run my `make package` on the project, the resulting debian uses that prefix directory instead of `/usr/local`.  I've tried doing an extra CMake `install()` command, which does work but then I still get an extra copy of the target output at the prefix directory location.

Here's the full `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project("sphinxbase")

find_package(Git REQUIRED)

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} STREQUAL "x86_64")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE amd64)
elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} STREQUAL "i686")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE i386)
endif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} STREQUAL "x86_64")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "Chuck Claunch <cclaunch@gmail.com>")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR 0)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH 1)
execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} rev-list master..
                COMMAND wc -l
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_REVISION
                OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
if(${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_PATCH_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
    message(STATUS "CMake older than 2.8.11, generating timestamp using execute_process().")
    execute_process(COMMAND date -u +%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE DATE_STRING
                OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
else(if (${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_PATCH_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 2.8.11))
    message(STATUS "CMake newer than 2.8.11, generating timestamp using string(TIMESTAMP).")
    string(TIMESTAMP DATE_STRING %Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S UTC)
endif(${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_PATCH_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} rev-parse HEAD
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_SHA_COMPLETE
                OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
string(SUBSTRING ${GIT_SHA_COMPLETE} 0 8 GIT_SHA_SHORT)
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_VERSION "${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH}.${GIT_REVISION}-${DATE_STRING}-${GIT_SHA_SHORT}")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_PROVIDES ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONFLICTS ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_REPLACES ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "bison, python-dev, swig")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "Sphinx speech recognition libraries")

set(SPHINXBASE_PREFIX_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/sphinxbase)
set(SPHINXBASE_SRC_DIR ${SPHINXBASE_PREFIX_DIR}/src/libsphinxbase)
set(SPHINXBASE_INSTALL_DIR ${SPHINXBASE_PREFIX_DIR}/install)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(libsphinxbase
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase
    GIT_TAG master
    PREFIX ${SPHINXBASE_PREFIX_DIR}
    DESTDIR ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND cd ${SPHINXBASE_SRC_DIR} && ./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=${SPHINXBASE_INSTALL_DIR}
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
)

add_custom_target(libsphinxbase-build
    DEPENDS libsphinxbase)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME ${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME}_${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_VERSION}_${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE})

include(CPack)
```

If I add a `install(DIRECTORY ${SPHINXBASE_INSTALL_DIR} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})` I end up with the correct installation but still have the extra copy that attempts to install at `${SPHINXBASE_INSTALLDIR}`.  If I run the build as sudo with no `PREFIX` in the `ExternalProject_Add` it works fine, but I don't want the build to run as sudo.

Is there some way I can force CPack to take the `${SPHINXBASE_INSTALL_DIR}` and only install that to `${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}`?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem today. Actually, if you run make package, cmake will run, including the make install part, which you do not want.
Try with "cpack" only as command line. It will build a package directly.

You can also do: DESTDIR=/tmp/truc make package

make package first run cmake which does a make install. 
cpack first set the install prefix to a temporary directory and run make install after.